# how to add web service client to gwt

Tags: java, web-services, gwt, glassfish

**Background**:
I have created a web service client `VoucherWebService` (consumed from an external Tomcat WSDL) which is currently deployed on a local Glassfish server (this server is also currently hosting my GWT project `MyGWT`).

I have found one way of calling `VoucherWebService` within the GWT project is by exporting `VoucherWebService` as an executable jar and then including it in `MyGWT` -- both in the build path and by putting it in WEB-INF/lib.

**Question**:
The above method works. However, the `VoucherWebService` jar file is *huge* and I get the feeling that I now have duplicate *resources* on the Glassfish server (i.e. `VoucherWebService` is already running on the server -- surely there *must* be an easier way of linking `MyGWT` with `VoucherWebService`). Should I be doing something else (e.g. export the auto generated `VoucherWebServiceEAR` project as .EAR file and use that instead)?

Comment: I do apologise if my (most-likely) incorrect verb usage, practices or general web-services ignorance throughout the question has made you screech. It has been one hell of a unguided and confusing first week in the world of web-services (I'm not even sure if web-services is what I should be calling it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to call webservice method from anywhere - not only from different application at the same container (server), but also from servers on the other site of globe (not considering networking issues of course ;)) without including JAR you mentioned.

Don't you try to use your webservice methods as a standard Java methods ? (e.g. importing some interface into your code, and calling methods on it in a standard Java way - I mean object.method())? If so, it's inappropriate usage of webservices (we cannot even use a word 'webservices' in this case).

Comment: You're right about calling the webservice from different containers (that is in fact what I'm trying to do) I forgot to add the word client -- already edited the question to reflect this. I've created a WS _client_ and I'm trying to add the WS _client_ (which running on the same container as the GWT project) to the GWT project (I was/am under the impression that the client is an interface to the webservice). Do I add an interface to the WS client via servlets (by adding it to web.xml?)

Comment: @fjudoit Ok, so you have application that exposes web services (it might run on some server in Europe), and another GWT application that use these webservices (consumes them) and it might be on some server in Africa. In such case your GWT application should contain webservice client JAR or to be such client itself. I think that your problem is with webservice client design / library references part - it should be relatively small application. Do you use some special framework in webservice client application?

Comment: I'm using Axis2. The WS client jar file is 40MB, maybe it's not huge, but I expect something waaaay smaller. I think you're right with the "GWT...be such client itself" suggestion. Then again, the African servers might also be my problem :)

Comment: Wow... 40MB is in my opinion huge for just webservice client... Did you try to create client as described e.g here:
http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide-creatingclients.html
?